# Transform data structures in R

Tags: r

The data structure I'm looking at is:

```
head(data)
  ID Gender      Location   Generation                           Question Response
1  2   Male South America Generation X Q0. Vote in the upcoming election?    0: No
2  2   Male South America Generation X                     Q1. Pulse Rate    0: No
3  2   Male South America Generation X                     Q2. Metabolism    0: No
4  2   Male South America Generation X                  Q3.Blood Pressure   1: Yes
5  2   Male South America Generation X                    Q4. Temperature    0: No
6  2   Male South America Generation X         Q5. Galvanic Skin Response   1: Yes
```

The column headers in this data frame are as follows:

```
> colnames(data)
[1] "ID"         "Gender"     "Location"   "Generation" "Question"   "Response"
```

The `Question` as the header contains the questions asked and so does the `Responses`. How I'd want to look at it is:

```
> colnames(final_data)
 [1] "ID"                                 "Gender"                            
 [3] "Location"                           "Generation"                        
 [5] "Q0. Vote in the upcoming election?" "Q1. Pulse Rate"                    
 [7] "Q134. Good Job Skills"              "Q135. Sense of Humor"              
 [9] "Q136. Intelligence"                 "Q137.Can Play Jazz"                
[11] "Q138.Likes the Beatles"             "Q139. Snobbiness"                  
[13] "Q140.Ability to lift heavy objects" "Q141.Grace under pressure"         
[15] "Q142.Grace on the dance floor"      "Q143.Likes animals"                
[17] "Q144.Makes good coffee"             "Q145.Eats all his/her vegetables"  
[19] "Q2. Metabolism"                     "Q3.Blood Pressure"                 
[21] "Q4. Temperature"                    "Q5. Galvanic Skin Response"        
[23] "Q6. Breathing"                      "Q7. Perspiration"                  
[25] "Q8.Pupil Dilation"                  "Q9. Adrenaline Production"
```

Currently I have the data which records the attributes for each ID in a single row. Essentially it means that each row has attributes for only one unique ID.

I saw another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711211/melt-strsplit-or-opposite-to-aggregate) but failed to understand it. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I fail to see the question. What are you trying to achieve? What is the desired result? Do you have a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt get how do you actually want the data to look finally.
My guess is that you want the data to have 
ID,Gender, Location,Generation as first 4 columns and then transform the questions into column names with their answers as values under those respective columns.
   To do that you can simply use `melt` and `dcast` functions in `reshape2` package in R

```
x=melt(data,id=c("ID","Gender","Location","Generation"))
#this will melt the data frame telling R that these 4 variables are your primary keys
final_data=dcast(x, ID + Gender + Location + Generation ~ Question, value.var="Response")
```

I think this will do the trick

Comment: Thanks a ton, i wanted to up-vote (clicked on the downwards arrow unintentionally). Now i dont have enough points to change. Thanks a ton Aayush, I will remember this trick. Really helped

Comment: Just curious...from this stage, how can I get the data to look like how it was?

Comment: You will again have to melt this new data and give id=c("ID","Gender","Location","Generation") it will revert the data to how it was